# Getting permission denied when using a URI despite FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION being set

Tags: android, uri, android-sharing

I have two android apps A and B.  I am passing a file from app A to app B and I am seeing that app B is getting the URI.  I am setting the `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` flag in app A and I am seeing that that `mFlags` is a 1, which is the value of `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION`, from within app B.  This is all good, but when I try to create a `FileInputStream` from the URI, I get a `FileNotFoundException (Permission denied)` exception.  What am I doing wrong?

Here are the pertinent code snippets:

In app A:

```
public void openTest Intent(String filePath) {
    Intent testIntent = new Intent("com.example.appB.TEST");
    testIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    testIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    testIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://"+filePath),"text/plain");
    try {
        startActivityForResult(testIntent, OPEN_NEW_TERM);      
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In app B:

```
@Override 
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    if (intent.getAction().equals("com.example.appB.TEST")) {
        Uri fileUri = intent.getData();
        File srcFile = new File(fileUri.getPath());
        File destFolder = getFilesDir();
        File destFile = new File(destFolder.getAbsolutePath()+srcFile.getName());
        try {
            copyFile(srcFile,destFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void copyFile(File src, File dst) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);  //**this is where it dies**
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst);

    // Transfer bytes from in to out
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```

It is when I am creating `in` that it gets the exception.  Any thoughts on why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

You are trying to use `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` for a file. That only works for `content://` `Uri` values, pointing to a stream served by a `ContentProvider`.

[Use `FileProvider`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) to serve up your files via such a `ContentProvider`. This is also covered in [a training guide](http://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/index.html), and [here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/V4FileProvider) demonstrating its use.

Comment: Yes, I had to specify the file provider and specify the shareable directories and use a content (not file) uri.  Thanks!